# Go to a specific UIViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a RootViewController which is in a navigationController. The RootViewController adds a new navigationController in a view container, that has several UIControllers, the last one is PersonalInfoViewController.

From personalInfoViewController I want to go back to RootViewController. My RootviewController is not the view.window.rootViewcontroller

[image]

Comment: You have 2 navigation controllers, one at the top level, and another that's inside a container view. When you say "From personalInfoViewController I want to go back to RootViewController" what do you mean? You want to go back to the root view controller of the contained navigation controller, or of the global navigation controller?

Comment: If you want to go to the root view controller of the global navigation controller you need some way to notify it. Perhaps have the top-level navigation controller add an observer for a "goBackToRoot" notification and then have the `PersonalInfoViewController` broadcast such a notification?

Comment: What  I want is to go to my RootViewController that contains the container in order to change what is in the container. If I use the notification/broadcast feature, I will have first to remove what is currently displayed no ? How shall I do that ?

Comment: Wait, what? Does each view controller in the top-level navigation controller's navigation stack have its own container view that contains another navigation controller and a personalViewController?

Comment: If you always want to go back to the root view controller of the top-level navigation controller then just use `popToRootViewController(animated:)`

Answer (score 0):

from any view controller of `personalInfoViewController`  Go back

```
self.view.window.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but you have to change Navigation like this image

```
  let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: personalInfoViewController())
        rootViewController.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Comment: This won't work since the Navigationcontroller is in a containerView in the root controller